# What should I be careful about before open sourcing an Android project?

Tags: android, open-source

As the title indicated, are there any things I should pay special attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing it. Open-source is not equal to open-source... 
There are many different open-source licenses. 
And even more frustrating is: they can conflict each other. 
Assume you are using two open-source libraries with License A and the other has License B, then it could be possible that you are not allowed to create a project using both of these libraries - depending on A and B.

Hence, in order to not exclude any other open-source software from making use of your project, and not to exclude anyone from using your open-source software, you should read a small article about the conflict issues, and the most-popular open-source licenses. 
There are two articles which helped me understanding the differences in open-source licenses:

1. [A short guide to open-source and similar licenses by Cameron Chapman](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/a-short-guide-to-open-source-and-similar-licenses/)
2. [Developer’s Guide to Open Source Licenses by David Marin](http://www.toptal.com/open-source/developers-guide-to-open-source-licenses)

Have fun, and may I be able to see some cool open-source releases of you in future!